# qt - What is the best way of aligning label headers to stay on top of a list of widgets as the window is resized

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

As you can see I have a vertical layout of some widgets that I can add to the UI dynamically. My question is, what is the best way of adding the header labels? Would it be best to create a custom layout for the headers with the same size options as the widgets below? At the moment the headers aren't aligned perfectly (see Power Cable header) and it gets even worse when the window is resized.

[image]

Comment: show your code.

Comment: have you tried a "Table View" and set the view headers from your label headers?

Comment: I thought about using a table view but I don't want the traditional table view 'look' (i.e like an excel spreadsheet). I don't think you can have different widgets in the cells of a table view can you?

Comment: @bananamana , you need a systematic approach .. the complex window with so many labels and widgets cant be managed "manually" .. the traditional table view 'look' is not the only way to display a view, yes widgets can be placed in the cells.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to do some reading on table views.

Comment: A `QGridLayout` would also ensure you align your labels and widgets vertically very easily. But depending on the interactions you need, a tree view would provide many useful methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to ensure the behaviour you described using layouts. The best option is use QTableView instead a layout based structure, due it seems you want to build a table, you don't need to reinvent the well using layouts because you have the QTableView class that implements directly.

I suggest this link start with QTableView:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html

PD: Remember you can edit the QTableVIew Style using CSS to change the look if you don't like the default style.